# Multiple Media queries doesn't work

Tags: css

I have different media queries for different devices, each of them works fine (if I leave only 1 of them), but if I put all media queries in my code only query with for large screen devices forks fine.

this one works fine:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px), screen and (max-height: 800px) {...}
```

and these don't work at all

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px), screen and (max-height: 360px) {...}
@media screen and (max-width: 360px), screen and (max-height: 640px) {...}
```

I need to make media query for every device (including landscape and normal mode).

How should I do this?

Comment: please add the complete css

Comment: @media screen AND (max-width: 640px) AND (max-height: 360px) { ... }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@media (max-height: 640px) and (max-width: 360px) {
    /* CSS stuff */
}

@media (max-height: 360px) and (max-width: 640px) {
    /* CSS stuff */
}
```

try to do it like this.

add this if you havent

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

you can also nest queries

```
@media  screen and  (min-height: 40px)  {
   @media  screen and  (min-width: 50px)  {
    /*enter css here to apply for both condition*/
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Visit this link. [Media Queries For Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Sample:

```css
/* ----------- Non-Retina Screens ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 
}

/* ----------- Retina Screens ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
}
```

See [this](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/) too.

```css
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  /* Styles */
}


/**********
iPad 3
**********/

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* Large screens ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1824px) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPhone 4 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPhone 5 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPhone 6 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  /* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  /* Styles */
}
```